# Email Message not delivered

Tags: gmail

I have sent an email from Gmail and The response from the remote server was: 553 sorry, relaying denied from your location [209.85.222.171], what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details like if you are sending the email from a personal Gmail account, form a G Suite account or from another email address. Alse add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score -1):

This is done by email servers to prevent spam mails which can potentially flood those mail servers. Here, in this case, you're most probably not authorized to use the mail server for relaying. Also, the error code 553 means that your email server domain is not in the list of allowed recipient hosts of the recipient to whom you were sending the mail.

More details and solution:
https://www.gammadyne.com/relaying_denied.htm